# Multiband UltraGrid only export the main band

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a UltraGrid in my application which displays the main band and further child bands. When i use the UltraGrid ExcelExporter the Exporter exports the whole grid with all child bands. I want to achieve that the exporter is only exporting the main band without all the child bands. So far i haven't found an property to achieve that. Any suggestions so far?

My export code looks like this (*just fyi*):

```
  this.saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.saveFileDialog.FileName))
            return;

        SplashScreenManager.ShowForm(typeof(FrmWait));
        try
        {
            this.ultraGridExcelExporter.Export(this.gridFrames,
                                                this.saveFileDialog.FileName);

            MessageBox.Show("Der Excel Export wurd erfolgreich durchgeführt.",
                            "Export erfolgreich",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            SplashScreenManager.CloseForm();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To skip exporting of all child band's rows you can handle InitializeRow event. If the row is in the root band you can skip all its descendants like this:

```
private void ultraGridExcelExporter1_InitializeRow(object sender, ExcelExportInitializeRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Band.Index == 0)
    {
        e.SkipDescendants = true;
    }
}
```

However this will still export several unnecessary column headers. To skip all but the first column header you can create a boolean field and handle HeaderRowExporting event like this:

```
private bool firstHeaderExported = false;

private void ultraGridExcelExporter1_HeaderRowExporting(object sender, HeaderRowExportingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.HeaderType == HeaderTypes.ColumnHeader && firstHeaderExported)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.firstHeaderExported = true;
    }
}
```

That should make the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The previous solutions listed here will work, but they are a bit inefficient because they rely on cancelling the export of each individual row.

A better way would be to take advantage of that fact that the UltraGridExcelExporter clones the grid's DisplayLayout. This means you can alter the export layout without affecting the on-screen grid. And you can simply hide all of the child bands:

```
    private void ultraGridExcelExporter1_ExportStarted(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.ExportStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (UltraGridBand band in e.Layout.Bands)
        {
            if (band.Index > 0)
                band.Hidden = true;
        }
    }
```

Or... even simpler in this case, just set the ViewStyle to SingleBand.

```
    private void ultraGridExcelExporter1_ExportStarted(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.ExportStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Layout.ViewStyle = ViewStyle.SingleBand;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the RowExporting event:

```
private void ultraGridExcelExporter_RowExporting(Object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.RowExportingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.GridRow.Band.Key != "MainBand")
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

(Please forgive me any syntax errors. I'm a VB developer.)